# initial open/toggle PluginDocumentSettingPanel panel in document setting block editor gutenberg

Tags: javascript, block-editor

i want make new panel inside document setting tab with React Script from this [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/slotfills/plugin-document-setting-panel/)

but the problem panel not toggle onload/initial i have try open with

```
dispatch('core/edit-post').toggleEditorPanelOpened('mycustom-panel')
```

but dont work,i see my custom panel not store in

```
select( 'core/edit-post' ).getPreference('panels')
```

so cant toggle it with `toggleEditorPanelOpened`

this my code to register PluginDocumentSettingPanel

```
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;

const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        name="mycustom-panel"
        title="Tips"
        className="mycustom-panel"
    >
        this is tips to write better content
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
);
registerPlugin( 'plugin-document-setting-panel-mycustom', { render: PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo, icon: null } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue in Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/22049).

You can get this working by passing  `{plugin-slug}/{panel-name}`

For your example, try:

`dispatch('core/edit-post').toggleEditorPanelOpened('plugin-document-setting-panel-mycustom/mycustom-panel')`

Comment: yes,work like i want